# Como baixar um programa de um repositório linux sem instalar?

Tags: linux, deepin

Gostaria de saber se é possível, se sim, como baixar um programa de um repositório linux sem instalá-lo. 
O motivo é que quase sempre que quero instalar um software, posso utilizar um comando no terminal que me permite instalar, porém nesse caso, gostaria de apenas baixar e armazenar o instalador.
Alguém sabe como proceder? O sistema que utilizo em específico é o Deepin.

Comment: Esta pergunta não pertence ao escopo do site, pois não possui relação com programação.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você talvez possa usar o seguinte comando:

```
sudo apt download <nome do(s) pacote(s)>
```

O download de um tar.gz com o .deb dentro será feito no diretório em que você estava ao executar o comando, porém ele pertencerá ao root. Para ter acesso basta usar:

```
sudo chmod 777 nome_do_arquivo.tar.gz
```

Depois falta só descompactar para achar o .deb.

Comment: O comando estava dando certo, estava baixando, porém o Deepin bloqueou o acesso e no final não deu certo. Mas enfim, é a resposta.